# fetch the data from the mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have created a login program using node currently i am get only the token from jwt and but i need username ,_id & mobile number also with the token which is  already stored in the database how to fetch this details. please help me i am new to node and mongo
 [image]

-------Schema------------

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var users = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    username: String,
    mobile: Number,
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users);

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const User = require('../models/users');
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(users => {
      if (users.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "This email does not exist please registor"
        });
      }

      console.log(users[0].password);
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, users[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth fail"
          });
        }
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign({
            email: users[0].email,
            userId: users[0]._id
          }, process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'login successfull',
            token: token
          });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({
            message: "password is incorrect"
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Please help me fetch username, id & mobile along with the token

Comment: You have to make token combining the username or id with timestamp or any other parameter..but there should be one unique key from user data...so that you when you decode that token,you can easily search for that id in user collection

Answer (score 0):

Add those information while creating token.

```
const token = jwt.sign({
        username: users[0].username,
        email: users[0].email,
        userId: users[0]._id,
        mobile: users[0].mobile
      }, process.env.JWT_KEY,
        {
          expiresIn: "1h"
        }
      );
```

Also you should use mongoose "findOne" instead of using "find" it will allow you to use user object like "user.email" rather than dealing with array and doing "users[0]".